# insert lines in notepad

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have nearly 9,000 lines in a text file in Notepad++

How do I find all lines that say

```
source:         DATA
```

and INSERT these 2 lines below that line?

```
delete:
password:       ACTUALPASSWORD
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `Ctrl-H` then earch for `source:         DATA` replace with `source:         DATA\r\ndelete:\r\npassword:       ACTUALPASSWORD\r\n`

This way you preserve new line formats.

Answer (score 1):

Change your  your **Search Mode**  to **extended**, and replace

```
source:         DATA
```

with

```
source:         DATA\ndelete:\npassword:       ACTUALPASSWORD
```

Comment: That's not working at all. It's not inserting the other new 2 lines.

Comment: That doesn't make sense. I'm trying to ADD those 2 lines because they do not exist in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

you search for
source:         DATA
and replace it with
source:         DATA
delete:
password:       ACTUALPASSWORD